# Can't serve gzipped files properly using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gzip, middleware

I have gzipped webpack bundle, and when I try to serve it, I get `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` error on the client-side.
Here is my middleware:

```
`app.get('*.js', function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + '.gz';
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
  next();
});`
```

Does anybody have any idea about what's happening? I've tried to use `.header()` or `.setHeader()` methods, but also haven't got any desired result.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here is plugin for compression:

```
new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
```

Comment: And, the data is actually sent as expected?  And, it actually is gzip?

Comment: Yes, I have gzipped bundle(gzipped by webpack, check my webpack config), and this bundle can't be served properly. I can serve plain js from this folder, but with .gz I get this problem.

Comment: Your webpack config isn't relevant... what was sent over the wire?  Was it what you expected?  Use something like Wireshark or a tool like Fiddler to help validate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this simply just by putting this midleware declaration:

```
app.get('*.js', function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + '.gz';
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
  console.log('sent')
  next();
});
```

before `app.use('/static', Express.static('dist'));`. (Earlier it was vice versa)

Comment: can you please share your entire file ? unable to understand your answer , well my code is like below
https://jsfiddle.net/30yjad6v/